# Next highest value when two of the numbers are the same

Tags: excel

I am trying to look up a cell based on the following formula:

=vlookup(large($A$2:$A$10,1),$A$2:$C$10,3,false) *for the maximum value*
=vlookup(large($A$2:$A$10,2),$A$2:$C$10,3,false) *for the second highest value*

*and so on*

My problem is when there are two values that are same in this part of the formula "(large($A$2:$A$10,2) but are different for the lookup value. For instance, when the series looks like this-

Max 10 (Car), 2 (Truck), 2 (Van), 4 (Motorcycle)

I return (Car), (Motorcycle), (Truck), (Truck) 
... instead of (Car), (Motorcycle), (Truck), (Van).

Does anyone know a solution to this using either a formula or vba?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... The only way I can think of doing this (but I would love to see other people's solutions) is creating an extra "helper column".

So suppose your data looked as follows:

```
ColA          ColB             ColC           ColD     
10            [whatever]       Car            [Formula]
2             [whatever]       Truck          [Formula]
2             [whatever]       Van            [Formula]
4             [whatever]       Motorcycle     [Formula]
```

I would add in a new Column between column A & B and put in a formula as follows

### In (New) B2:

```
=A2 + COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)/100
```

Now, when you drag it down, it will increment every repeated value by 0.01, looking as follows:

```
ColA        ColB         ColC             ColD           ColE     
10          10.01        [whatever]       Car            [Formula]
2           2.01         [whatever]       Truck          [Formula]
2           2.02         [whatever]       Van            [Formula]
4           4.01         [whatever]       Motorcycle     [Formula]
```

Then just update your Vlookup formula to start looking in column B rather than column A.

Hope this makes sense...

Comment: This looks like the best solution to me as well. I'd make one alteration to the formula so that it better handles values repeated more than twice - instead of adding `0.01` to `A2`, adding `COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)/1000` would mean that each duplicate would be incremented by a unique amount.

Comment: Agreed! @Mischinab - Almost missed that :) - Updating my solution accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: This is a good solution. I was half way there creating a helper column but I was using whole values instead of .01 or something smaller. Using whole values could potentially mess up my original count (your ColA) but with the decimal values I won't have that problem. Thanks.

Comment: ... you know what, you can do this without the `If` statement too... Solution updated again....

Answer (score 0):

Can you not sort the table, descending, on Column A?  Then your Excel formulas could be:

```
=vlookup($A2,$A2:$C$10,3,false) 
=vlookup($A3,$A3:$C$10,3,false)
=vlookup($A4,$A4:$C$10,3,false)
```

Actually, easier than that, your formulas could just be:

```
=$C2
=$C3
```